# Can notepad++ support sqlcmd syntax somehow?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, notepad++, sqlcmd

I like using notepad++ for my syntax editing because it can handle all the languages I work in.

However, when I load a TSQL script that uses SQLCMD stuff, it messes up the highlighting.

For example, if you have a sql file with this in it `:setvar DefaultDataPath "D:\Data\"` then everything after that will be light grey.

Is there a way to tell notepad++ to not do that?

Answer (score 1):

It seems the issue here is coming from the \" at the end of your line.  Notepad++ appears to be translating that as an escaped quote (") so it believes to still be in the same string.

I have not seen anything in Notepad++ that would automatically fix this for you (but to be honest I did not look too much into it).  Some alternative options:

```
"D:\Data"
"D:\Data\""
"D:\Data\\"
```

I notice Notepad++ having these types of problems quite often but they are purely cosmetic issues.